# how to handle throttling with MSGraphClient while sending email

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

i am using below code to send email using microsoft graph

await graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync()

Since post operation doesnt return anything then how to detect status code 429 (Throttle response code)and handle it.

Comment: If there is throttling you will get the HTTP 429 back in response. So watch for the HTTP resource, monitor and handle/implement the business logic to overcome throttling at your end.

Comment: Hi, since graphserviceclient does not return any response for post operation, how will you check for the same?

Comment: Who said so... PostAsync() method should throw a ServiceException on error.

Comment: Let me add an example below in answer, so that it can correctly format it. Test it and confirm if it works for you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostAsync() method should throw a ServiceException on error. For example:

```
try
{
     await graphClient.Users[userId].SendMail(message).Request().PostAsync();
} 
catch (Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dev.. got response from Microsoft developer community too. according to them , no need to check 429 status . graphserviceclient automatically retries . in case of too many retries, client throws toomanyretries service exception

Comment: Good to hear!! Thanks for updating the same @riks. Its useful to other members in the community as well.